# Extended meaning of PLACHUTTA

Tags: word-usage

Chess is one of the few sports that offers a cornucopia of words, which are used in ordinary parlance. *checkmate*, *stalemate*, *zugzwang*, and *gambit* are a few well-known words that owe their origin to the sport of chess.

I came across a new chess word very recently: *plachutta*.

Here is how Wikipedia defines the word:

> The Plachutta is a device found in chess problems: a white piece sacrifices itself on a square where it could be captured by one of two similarly moving black pieces (for example, a bishop and a queen moving along a diagonal, or two rooks) moving along a different line; whichever black piece captures, it interferes with the other.

My question is how could this word be used in an ordinary context like we use the other chess terminology.

Comment: *My question is how could this word be used in an ordinary context* - first teach the world the meaning of "plachutta" (which fewer that 1 in 1,000 will know) and then let them develop it into a metaphor... This may take some time.

Comment: I've never come across the word _zugzwang_!

Comment: Kate Bunting:  It's a situation in which the obligation to make a move in one's turn is a serious, often decisive, disadvantage.

Comment: Fair enough, Greybeard!

Comment: If you're interested, here's Youtube, [Prize Problem by J. Plachutta No.6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJaOy5IiO_4) - *One of a set of problems by **Signor James Plachutta of Venice** that won a prize in the **1862 Chess Congress.***

Comment: @KateBunting as 'zugzwang' is German I wonder whether it is better known in Gernan-speaking countries. Looking up the translations of the components online  I see that it can also be meaningful in German without referring to chess. 'Checkmate', 'stalemate' and 'gambit' are chess terms which have entered everyday languagee, I suspect that zugzwang has the opposite history.

Comment: @BoldBen I'm sure it must be, if the OP thinks it's 'used in ordinary parlance'. I think I have a pretty large vocabulary, but I've never heard it.

Comment: 'Fianchetto' is probably an older and more familiar term, but it doesn't seem to have broadened into everyday usage. What do dictionaries say? ELU looks at established usage, not fanciful novel metaphors.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as only people interested in chess problems will know the reference, I question the usefulness of using the term "Plachutta" for any metaphorical sense. By the way, this chess tactic is named Plachutta after a chess problemist Joseph Plachutta; it is not an ordinary vocabulary word.

To explain in more detail:  There are White pieces A1, A2, C and Black pieces B1, B2. White has 2 threats A1->W1, A2->W2. B1 guards W1;  B2 guards W2; their lines of guard cross at X. White plays C->X. If B1 takes at X, B1 is *overloaded*: it must now guard both W1 and W2. So now White plays A2->W2. Black must now take at W2 with B1 rather than B2, because B1 is in B2's way -- B1 *interferes* with B2. White has now *decoyed* B1 away from where Black wanted it. White now plays A1->W1 which Black cannot parry because B1 no longer guards W1.

I can't see any situation where the chess term for this specific set-up would be a better metaphor than a well-known word such as "overload", "interfere" or "decoy".

Comment: I appreciate your rationale for dropping a supposedly gratuitous synonym of _decoy_, _interfere_, _overload_, and other related words, but going by this logic we shouldn't have mainstreamed other such technical words either. As it is, we often see _stalemate_, _checkmate_, and many other words used in ordinary contexts, though they might have raised eyebrows at some point for much the same reason. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Part of my point in suggesting *decoy* etc. was to show that a Plachutta is complex, and to suggest a better word for whatever part of it you wanted to liken something to. And yes, I see *stalemate* used metaphorically -- for a situation where neither side can progress. But "stalemate" is unsuitable because stalemate ends the game, and anyway we already have well-known metaphors for that meaning, e.g. deadlock, standoff and impasse. Let's not make a similar mistake.

Comment: Rosie F: I see. Thank you for your insights :)

Answer (score 0):

It often happens that two lanes of traffic must merge to one lane. There is plachutta as one of the lead vehicles manages to be first. Similarly when two people arrive at a narrow door: with the amusing *“After you”*. *“No, after you”* type of exchange.

Comment: The traffiic situation is one where [rule 134 of the Highway Code](https://www.highwaycodeuk.co.uk/multi-lane-carriageways.html) should apply. Unfortunately most UK drivers don't seem to be aware of it.

Comment: Indeed not. But rule 134a/u/d/i  says that Audi drivers must drive aggressively in the outside lane so as to shove in front of all other cars at the lane confluence.

Comment: That's a very good argument for everyone using 'alternate merging' othewise known as 'zip merging'. If everyone did that there'd be nowhere for the plonker to overtake and he'd just have to sit and fume like everyone else